# 3rd party website service which requires JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am putting together a service which offers some tracking / analytics style functionality, and the plan is to offer this out to any users to include on their website where they can simply paste in a reference to an external javascript file.  The JavaScript code currently relies on JQuery as it is far quicker, easier and more robust to code it in this way however I am now unsure as to how is best to include this reference on the users site - some of the sites using the service may have JQuery, some may not and those that do will likely have differing versions.  Is there a best practice here?  Options I have come up with:

1. Include minified JQuery (possibly custom build with only the functionality I need) with a custom JQuery alias in the external JS file
2. Load Jquery from the external JS file (again using custom JQuery alias)
3. Use a conditional loader such as [yepnopejs](http://yepnopejs.com) to ensure that JQuery is installed
4. Document the requirement to have JQuery installed and leave it up to the user to ensure it is there and a compatible version

My concerns with 3 is that future versions of JQuery may be incompatible (although this is very unlikely as it's only core functionality being used).  I also want to avoid 4 as the users may not be that technical and any issues may put them off using this service altogether

Is there a further solution I have missed?

Comment: What analytics are you trying to do and why does it require jQuery?

Comment: "this is very unlikely as it's only core functionality being used" — core functionality like `$.browser` or `$('foo').live`?

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer - the analytics are mainly to do with outbound link tracking and tracking integration with a number of third party systems. JQuery is not necessarily required however it makes the development quicker and more robust as all of the cross browser issues will (should) be resolved for example.

Comment: @Quentin - this is why I am not 100% confident that any functionality in JQuery won't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dirty trick - jQuery has a jsonp callback to a function named define, so that it will work properly with AMD. You can use the define callback as a jsonp callback to run code that depends on jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Maybe jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=status>jQuery loading...</div>

<!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script>
function jQueryReady() {
    // Place your on-jQuery-load statements here
    $('#status').text('jQuery loaded.');
}
if (!window.jQuery) {
    define = jQueryReady;
    define.amd = { jQuery: true };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
    script.async = true;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
} else {
    jQueryReady();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://brass9.com/test/maybe-jquery/

Since your question says you're using this on third-party sites that could have basically anything, I've modified the answer slightly to ensure this code does (less) harm to existing libraries if present on the page - it actually will still harm libs like require.js if require has loaded and jQuery has not, which with asynchrony is entirely possible. I'll update later to resolve this issue.

Previous answer (doesn't work as David noted):

```
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
}
</script>
<script>
// Work with jQuery as needed
</script>
```

Comment: this won't work: when you execute the second script block jQuery won't be available

Comment: @DavidFregoli You're right good catch - normally I test in jsfiddle but this wasn't possible with this one - I've updated my answer to avoid any settimeouts, document.writes, etc by leveraging jQuery's callback at the end of its code (normally for AMD, but you can use it for your own jsonp callback).

Comment: Thanks for this - my script would need to work then with whatever version of query the webpage has loaded (if they have one). I'm not 100% confident that query wouldn't change, is it possible to test for a version / specific functionality?

Comment: I believe the version of jQuery where this jsonp callback was added was jQuery 1.7; prior to that version you'd have to resort to more brutal workarounds like setTimeout/setInterval as in David's solution; more broadly you can see LabJs's well-tested cross-browser method of doing this for any script here, but it's quite long: https://gist.github.com/getify/603980 You could also serve your own version of jQuery that simply has your own jsonp callback appended to the end to make things very simple.

Comment: If I was to server my own version of JQuery with it's own jsonp, would it make more sense just to compile my own custom, minimal JQuery package, and distribute it using a custom alias?

Comment: Yeah you could use something like Closure Compiler with Advanced Optimizations turned on to deliver your own complete script (including the slice of jquery in use) that doesn't interact with any scripts on the page whatsoever. Likely safer since you don't know if the jquery you detect on the page isn't itself modified. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

Comment: Nice link, not come across that, will check it out.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example on how to require jQuery if needed:

```
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
(function ready(){
    if(window.jQuery) {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function() {
               // Your plugin code
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(ready, 50);
    }
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Good answer, although document.write should probably be avoided.

Comment: `document.write()` is perfectly fine to use in the `head` and before the `dom` has loaded. It's even used by the html5 boilerplate in a similar way.

Comment: Running it in the head tags would be even worse - you want to push all script execution to the end of the body that you can. If this were in the head tags and jQuery hadn't loaded, you'd be making the browser freeze with a blank page while jQuery loads - which may time out, leaving the user with a blank page for quite some time.

Comment: it doesn't need to be in the `head` anyway. And the `script` tag is ALWAYS blocking, unless you use `async`.